# setTextColor programmable using color value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I need to set text color in adapter class not on activity and using color value that record in colors.xml file !

and this is the code: sorry for any missing things 
and this is the code: sorry for any missing things 
and this is the code: sorry for any missing things

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.myViewHolder> {
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsHashMapList;

/*int[] images = {
        R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground
};*/

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsJsonList){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.productsHashMapList = productsJsonList;

}

@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
    myViewHolder holder = new myViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder._productName.setText(productsHashMapList.get(position).get("name"));
    holder._productName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productsHashMapList.size();
}

public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView   _imgview;
    TextView    _productName;


    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        _imgview            = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        _productName           = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add your adapter code here!!

Comment: @Anas , Please accept or upvotes the below any solution which is workable, for u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all pass the context through the constructor of the adapter from Activity while initializing the adapter in activity and set context in the adapter:

```
this.context = context; // set this in the constructor.
```

Then, set the textColor:

```
textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white)); //whatever your color
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
textViewOBJ.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color_code));
```

**FYI**

You should pass [**`Context`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context).

How?

Through your Adapter class. #**Contsructor**

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsHashMapList;
   Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context contextOBJ, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsJsonList){
    this.context=contextOBJ;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.productsHashMapList = productsJsonList;

}
```

Comment: this message appear: cannot resolve symbol 'context'.
i think because this in a class not on activity

Comment: @Anas check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

`textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color));`

as per prashanth verma anser, initailize context in contsructor.
Then use it in code.

`textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color));`

Comment: cannot resolve method 'getResources()

Comment: as per prashanth verma anser, initailize context in contsructor.

Answer (score 0):

Always set the text color inside your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class, not inside the `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter class, have a look on the below solution

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 private TextView YOUR_TEXT_VIEW;
        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        YOUR_TEXT_VIEW = view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW);

        YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(YOUR_APP_CONTEXT, R.color.your_color_code));

        }


    }
```